# c - swap function for singly linked list of strings

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a swap function for my linked list.

The initialization is as follows

```
typedef struct node
{
    char data[50]; // data
    struct node *next; // a pointer to next node
} Node;

typedef Node* NodePtr;
```

In one of my functions I try to swap two functions by using

```
swap(&(p->data), &(q->data));
```

where `p` and `q` are `NodePtr`'s.

My swap function is as follows:

```
void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
   char *t; // temporary

   t = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = t;
} // end swap()
```

I keep getting the following error : `[Error] cannot convert 'char (*)[50]' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'void swap(char*, char*)'`

I know this means that I need to change how I declare my functions but I am just not sure how to change them to correctly do what I want.

Comment: The problem is that `data` isn't a pointer, it's an array, and your swap function only works if `data` is a pointer. You have two choices -- a) make `data` a pointer (and deal with memory management), or b) copy the bytes of the array in the swap function.

Comment: The swap functionality you're *apparently* trying to implement has *nothing* to do with a linked list. All this seems to be trying to do is swap char buffers, and misses the boat in declaration, addressing *and* dereferencing. What is the actual *problem* you're trying to solve? "A swap function for a linked list" isn't the problem. What is said-function supposed to *do*  and how is it supposed to be *used* ??

Comment: @WhozCraig it was just a sorting function I was playing with.

Comment: @user3386109 I would prefer to make data the pointer. Thanks for the feedback - much appreciated

Comment: @user2958395 So you're toying with sorting a linked list? Is that right? I ask because ideally once data is in a linked list, node you don't futz with the guts (the regular data members). Rather, you rearrange *pointers* (the `next` members and potentially your linked list `head` pointer), not the regular data *in* the nodes. It is somewhat the point of linked lists: their arrangement can be manipulated independent of the non-list-management members. That said, if you're still set on this, your swap function should take two `Node*` parameters and swap the `data` content via temp copies.

Comment: @WhozCraig I am learning about C so I was trying to implement sorting functions to the linked list just to see if this was possible and for any speed enhancements I could gain. I understand that I should not manipulate the data in this way - now. Thanks for teaching me good practices. I would do what you suggested just to get it working but with the knowledge that this is not the way to go about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code on how to swap two strings in a structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct a
{
    char c[50];
};

void swap(char *p,char *q)
{
    char t[50] = "";
    strcpy(t,p);
    strcpy(p,q);
    strcpy(q,t);
}
int main(void) {
    struct a *A = malloc(sizeof(struct a));
    struct a *B = malloc(sizeof(struct a));
    strcpy(A->c,"some");
    strcpy(B->c,"string");
    printf("%s %s\n",A->c,B->c);
    swap(A->c,B->c);
    printf("%s %s\n",A->c,B->c);
    free(A);
    free(B);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted and thus I will accept it. But I now know that this is not the best way to manipulate linked lists